# Call helper from RABL template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have a helper, controller and template like:

*Helper:*

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(access_token: access_token)
  end

  private
    def access_token
      pattern = /^Bearer /
      header  = request.headers["Authorization"]
      header.gsub(pattern, "") if header && header.match(pattern)
    end
end
```

*Controller:*

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/companies_controller.rb
class Api::V1::CompaniesController < Api::V1::BaseController

  before_action :set_company, only: [:show]

  def show
    render @company
  end


  private
    def set_company
      @company ||= Company.find(params[:id])
    end
end


# app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

*RABL-Rails template:*

```
object :@company

attributes :id, :name, :description, :website

# --- How can I call a helper method here?
# if (@company.owner?(current_user) or current_user.kind_of?(Admin))
#  attributes :contact
# end

attributes :created_at, :updated_at
```

When I call a helper method from RABL template, it will raise an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<RablRails::Compiler:0x00000002494c68>
```

How can I call a helper method from RABL template?

Note: I used `gem rabl-rails '~> 0.4.1'`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your calling it the right way but the real problem is that your controller doesn't have inheritance from ApplicationController (unless there is more in `Api::V1::BaseController` that we can't see). So this means that your probably not getting ApplicationHelper included.

I would suggest you just add it to your controller

```
class Api::V1::CompaniesController < Api::V1::BaseController
include ApplicationHelper
...
end
```

Comment: Actually, `Api::V1::BaseController` extends `ApplicationController`, which I also put `include ApplicationHelper` in there.